# How to get intext info between tags with Xpath?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to retrieve an article number and some other data with the help of Xpath, where the ID is within an div tag surrounded by other HTML tags and text:

```
<div class="description">
    <span class="product-name"></span><br>
    details<br>
    company<br>
    Art.-Nr. (article): 1686382
    <div class="product-icons"></div>
</div>
```

My Xpath looks like this

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@id="product-list"]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]').extract_first()
```

response:

```
'<div class="description">\n<span class="product-name"><b><a href="/gurgelloesungen-tropfen/salviathymol-n-madaus-p11548439">Salviathymol N Madaus</a></b></span><br>\nTropfen, 100 Milliliter, N3<br>\nMEDA Pharma GmbH &amp; Co. KG<br>\nArt.-Nr. (PZN): 11548439\n<div class="product-icons">\n<div class="rating"><a href="/gurgelloesungen-tropfen/salviathymol-n-madaus-p11548439#reviews" class="sp2p sp-star sp-star-5"></a><span>(<a href="/gurgelloesungen-tropfen/salviathymol-n-madaus-p11548439#reviews">13</a>)</span></div>\n</div>\n</div>'
```

How can I retrieve the three lines of data (details, company, article no)?

Comment: I solved it but do not know why it works: response.xpath('//div[@id="product-list"]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/br[3]//following-sibling::text()').extract_first()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code will return the `node` rather the `text`. If you have to get the text then you have to point to the `text` node using `text()`.

That's the reason why your below line of code extracted the text.

```
response.xpath('//div[@id="product-list"]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/br[3]//following-sibling::text()').extract_first()
```